# How to use spies in testing factories with promises?

Tags: node.js, testing, promise, mocha.js, chai

I would like to test this code:

```
'use strict';

var Promise = require('bluebird');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs-extra'));
var path = require('path');

var dispatcher = function() {
  return {
    /**
     * @param {Object} options
     * @param {string} options.s3_access_key
     * @param {string} options.s3_secret_key
     * @param {string} options.s3_bucket
     * @param {string} options.file - Path to the file to be uploaded
     * @param {string} [options.file_key] - Name to save the file under, defaults to the original file's name
     * @returns {Function} Promise - A promise resolved with `true` or rejected with an Error
     */
    upload: Promise.method(function upload(options) {
      var s3_options = {
        accessKeyId: options.s3_access_key,
        secretAccessKey: options.s3_secret_key,
        params: {
          Bucket: options.s3_bucket
        }
      };
      var file_stream = fs.createReadStream(options.file);
      var file_key = options.file_key || path.basename(options.file);
      var promisedS3 = Promise.promisifyAll(new AWS.S3(s3_options));

      return promisedS3.putObjectAsync({
        Body: file_stream,
        Key: file_key
      });
    })
  };
};

module.exports = {
  create: dispatcher
};
```

I know how to do the integration test, but I would also like to verify that `promisedS3` gets called with the right arguments. I think I need to use a spy for that but I am not sure how to "plug" myself into promisedS3.putObjectAsync from the test to intercept the arguments and compare them.

I would like to avoid wrapping the call to S3 in a private method and keep using a factory.

Comment: Have you looked into using sinon?

Comment: I have but I'm not sure I fully understand how to tap into the `promisedS3` object from my code. I can `var spy = sinon.spy(require('./dispatcher'), 'upload');` but I don't see how it helps me spy on the `promisedS3.putObjectAsync` call.

Comment: Please call `promisifyAll` on the prototype of an object and not on every new instance - it will be significantly faster.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, if I do `Promise.promisifyAll(AWS.S3)`, it won't work: `TypeError: Cannot promisify an API that has normal methods with 'Async'-suffix

    See http://goo.gl/iWrZbw`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited after comments)

In your tests you can use libs like [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to stub/mock external dependencies.

I just tested this out and it works:

```
'use strict';

var sinon = require( 'sinon' );
var proxyquire = require( 'proxyquire' );
var expect = require('must');

var awsStub = {
    S3: function(){
    },
    '@noCallThru': true
};

var fsStub = {
    createReadStream: function(){
        return {};
    },
    '@noCallThru': true
};

describe( 'S3 uploader', function(){
    var subject, spy;
    beforeEach( function(){
        spy = sinon.spy();
        awsStub.S3.prototype.putObject = function( params, callback ){
            spy(params);
            callback();
        };
        subject = proxyquire( '../lib/s3uploader', {
            'aws-sdk': awsStub,
            'fs-extra': fsStub
        } );

    } );
    it( 'should delegate to AWS S3 `putObject`', function( done ){
        subject().upload( {file:''} ).then( function(){
            expect( spy.callCount ).to.equal( 1 );
            done();
        } )
    } );
} );
```

Where `lib/s3uploader` is the file you posted above.

By default the original method of the stubbed dependency will still be called. If you don't want that you need to pass `@noCallThru: true` to the proxyquire call, as above.

Comment: `Promise.promisfyAll(new AWS.S3());` makes this not work. I can't access `promisedS3`, I think, because it is not in the module's global scope. And if I mock `AWS.S3.putObject`, I can see the mock when I inspect the `AWS.S3` object from within `upload`, but when I `new AWS.S3()` and then promisify it, the `putObject` method isn't the mock.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't realize it's a "class". As Benjamin Gruenbaum wrote you have to promisify the prototype, not the instance. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Why should I promisify the prototype rather than the instance? If I run your code without a stub but with nock to simulate the API calls and answers to S3, `promisedS3.putObjectAsync` fails because the `putObjectAsync` method is indefined. I think it passes in your example because you stub it so it didn't exist on the original object but because you create it on your stub then the code runs.

Comment: _Normally_ it's better to promisify the prototype, since it only needs to happen once. But you're quite right, in this case it won't work anymore. So, the solution is to promisify the instance as you did before. Just tested it out with the mocked _and_ the unmocked and it works in both.